# How to get closest 100 documents in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, mongodb-query, database, nosql

I want to query a database for the first 100 documents that are closest to me in MongoDB. Once I have the closest 100 documents, I want to sort them by custom fields in the documents. Such as `createdAt` or `points`. It seems like `$near` is what I want, but their docs say:

`When using sort() with geospatial queries, consider using $geoWithin operator, which does not sort documents, instead of $near.`

So it seems like they suggest using `$geoWithin`, but I don't want to constrain the search to a specific range. Suggestions?

Comment: that's an interesting problem, are you only limiting this to aggregation / query? or are you allowing python / nodejs driver?  can't think of a great way to do it with aggregation / query, but if you are using python / nodejs, you'll need a combination of $near and then get the top 100 closest points by calculating distance from the original point.

Comment: I would be using a NodeJS driver. Do you know of any examples of this or tutorials? I'm pretty new to Mongo.